# Re-Run the program and get different results C# UWP vs2019

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2019

Problem solved.  See the comments from FayWang below.

Added info.

Ok. I added some code to delete the items. Deleting (one at a time). When seeing one image .. all 25 are being created to the same spot. The problem is in the Sub to create the new images. Some of them have no image, like the source was not set. Doesn't explain why they all have the same coordinates. And then the next load may work properly, or not.

---

I am probably going to feel really stupid, but....

I just built a quick and short program (C# UWP VS 2019). It is going to build 25 images to the screen. I was going to add a remove them all button (trying to find a memory leak) and add them back but never got that far.

The program compiles no errors. I run it. Usually, instead of 25 images, I SEE 1. On the first run.  Just run it again (no rebuild or code changes) and I may get the 25. I cant tell what will happen.

After the last build, in 10 runs, I got  1, 25, 1, 25, 25, 1, 25, 25, 25, 1

Also, on the 1 image ones.  They seem to be in different places.

I am putting the full code below.  I often make mistakes.  But this is just re-running the code.

Also, I just re-installed Visual studio this morning too.

[image: One Smiley]

---

[image]

---

First the Xaml inside the Page tag, then the code behind

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
        <Rectangle x:Name="CutCopyRect"
                    Height="980" Width="1480"
                    Fill="LemonChiffon" 
                    Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>
    </Canvas>
```

```
    public MainPage()
    {  this.InitializeComponent();
        DrawSomeImages();
    }

    void DrawSomeImages()
    {for (int iCt1 = 0; iCt1 < 5; iCt1++)
        { for (int iCt2 = 0; iCt2 < 5; iCt2++)  
            {  makeImage(iCt1, iCt2); }  
        }
    }

    void makeImage(int inTop, int inLeft)
    {   try
        { 
            Image img1 = new Image();
            img1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SmileyAngry.png"));
            img1.Width = 220;
            img1.Height = 220;
            img1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (inTop * 38));
            img1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (inLeft * 39));
            MyCanvas.Children.Add(img1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string thisProc = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("Error Message: ", ex.Message, "  In " + thisProc);
        }
    }
```

Comment: when you explicitly set the width of the image, it's better to set DecodePixelWidth property of BitmapImage. it will load the BitmapImage with the specified width. Helps with memory usage and speed when loading large images. If you set the `bitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth = 220;`, will the same issue occur?

Comment: Hi Faywang - MSFT  and Thx.  I tried to do as you suggested.  Since it is type of Image, the decodePixelWidth is not availilable.  So, I tried using a Bitmabimage instead. It looked promising, but then I could not set the Source URI. That required a beginBlock, which is not available. That also seemed to remove access to .Name  This really looked promising, since the spark for throwing this program together is looking for a memory leak.

Comment: Hi @Faywang. Thx.  I tried to do as you suggested.  After searching for a while, I think I got close using
 
   Image img1 = new Image();
   BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png"));                                
   img1.Width = bi.DecodePixelWidth = 110;
   img1.Height = bi.DecodePixelHeight = 110;
  
I think that the 2nd line is not correct & no source found.  The objects are being created, etc. but nothing displayed.

Comment: Do you have the image named "Logo.png" in Assets? And Have you set the source of Image as bi like `img1.Source = bi;`?

Comment: @FayWang ..Thank You. So far, it is always popping up the 25 images. The image was there. The new line of code did it. I don't see any way to mark this as the answer. Ill do that if I find it.

Comment: Hi, I have compiled the comments into the answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you explicitly set the width of the image, it's better to set **DecodePixelWidth** property of BitmapImage. it will load the BitmapImage with the specified width. Helps with memory usage and speed when loading large images.

```
Image img1 = new Image(); 
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, "ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png")); 
img1.Width = bi.DecodePixelWidth = 110; 
img1.Height = bi.DecodePixelHeight = 110;
img1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, (inTop * 38));
img1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (inLeft * 39));
img1.Source = bi;
MyCanvas.Children.Add(img1);
```

Comment: Just one comment.  When I did this for an image in a StoryBoard (it did a a zoom to grow the image), it really screwed up the picture. Most likely something that I did, but right now I dont have time to chase it down.  I just didn't do it for the 2 storyboards affected.

Comment: This Answer, was mostly correct.  I applied it to my real code. It worked untill I tried to use it with a StoryBoard.  After, I submitted this to Microsoft in feedback.  There is a bug there somewhere in the XAML core.. think I said that right.  Anyway, its now a confirmed issue and hopefully on someones  todo list.